# A topological vector space $X$ is separable if its dual space $X^*$ is separable?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological vector space such that the associated dual space $X^*$ is separable. Can we say that $X$ is separable ?

I know that this property is valid for Banach spaces but for topological vector spaces, I have no idea.

Comment: Just consider a non-separable $X$ with $X^*=\{0\}$. Maybe you want $X$ to be locally convex.

Comment: Since we know this is true for Banach spaces and false for a rather exotic lcs example, I am tempted to ask if there is a positive answer for some of the central classes of well-behaved spaces—the obvious candidates are the (lc) Fréchet spaces and $(DF)$-spaces.

Answer (score 14):

YCor has given a counterexample for topological vector spaces. The statement is still false for locally convex spaces. Consider the space $X$ defined to be a locally convex coproduct of $\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}\R$, $\R$-many times. So $X$ is the space of functions $\R \rightarrow \R$ that are zero except for on a finite subset of $\R$, equipped with the locally convex coproduct topology.

The dual space $X^* \cong \R^\R$ by the usual pairing of an element of $X$ with an element of $\R^\R$ by summation, and for the topology it doesn't matter whether we take the strong dual topology or the weak-* topology, either way we get the usual product topology on $\R^\R$. This space is separable, because the polynomial functions with rational coefficients $\R \rightarrow \R$ forms a countable dense subset.

However, $X$ itself is not separable. If $X$ were separable, we would have some countable set $D \subseteq X$ such that each $f \in \R^\R$ is determined by its values when paired with each $\phi \in D$. But since each element of $D$ has finite support, $D$ only determines countably many "coordinates" in $\R^\R$, so we could pick two $f_1,f_2 \in \R^\R$ agreeing on those elements of $\R$ but not being equal. This contradicts $D$ being dense.

Instead of an $\R$-fold coproduct we could have taken any $\kappa$-fold coproduct where $\aleph_0 < \kappa \leq 2^{\aleph_0}$, by the Hewitt-Marczewski-Pondiczery theorem.

Comment: Very cool example!

Comment: For $X^*$ to be ${\mathbb R}^{\mathbb R}$, every linear functional on $X$ must be continuous. That is, the initial topology must be locally convex. Is this obvious?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე That depends on what you mean by "initial topology". It *is* true that every linear functional is continuous (and it has to be, to be a coproduct). However, the topological vector space initial topology and locally convex initial topology are not identical for uncountable coproducts. This is why I specified the "locally convex coproduct topology" (which should be considered as one word, rather than as saying that the copduct topology is locally convex). See Schaefer's *Topological Vector Spaces* section II.6. The coproduct is called the "locally convex direct sum" there.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. It is subtler than I expected, I thought you meant that the topological vector space coproduct is locally convex in this case, which is presumably not true.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე In terms of counterexamples, in Schaefer it is just not stated that the two are the same, and the fact that they are the same for a $\aleph_0$-fold coproduct is set as an exercise. But in [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/8660/61785) and [this comment by Paul Garrett](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/164007/test-functions-with-wrong-topology-not-locally-convex?rq=1#comment418809_164010) links are provided to counterexamples for the case of an uncountable coproduct.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\Gamma$ be a set and consider the product measure $\mu^{\otimes \Gamma}$, where $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure on the unit interval. For any $p\in (0,1)$, the space $L_p(\mu^{\otimes \Gamma})$ has trivial dual because $\mu^{\otimes \Gamma}$ is atomless. However, when $\Gamma$ is uncountable, the space $L_p(\mu^{\otimes \Gamma})$ is non-separable.